# select loaded with xmlhttp doesn't get send with form

Tags: php, javascript, html

I'm working on a chrome-extension for a small bookmarking site. The extention-popup fills a form with the browsers current url, title, selected text. The problem is, that I with a javascripts xmlhttp call to the webserver have loaded an div inside the form with a select-option.

When I send the form, the selected option from the select-option doesn't get send with the rest of the form.

The form:

```
<form action="removed" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="popup_form">
        <span class="input_header">Titel</span>
        <input class="calendar_add_form_Date" type="text" name="title">

        <span class="input_header">URL</span>
        <input class="calendar_add_form_Date" type="text" name="url">

                <span class="input_header">NOTE</span>
      <textarea id="note" name="note" style="height: 60px;"></textarea>

      <span class="input_header">Tags</span>
      <input class="calendar_add_form_Date" type="text" id="tags" name="tags">
      <div id="url"></div>


</div>
</div>

<div id="popup_footer"><input class="btn btn_blue" style="" value="&nbsp;Add&nbsp;" type="submit"/>

<div id="sets">
</div>
```

Read later

The javascript call:

```
function loadSets()
{
var xmlhttp;
  xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
    if(xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
      document.getElementById("sets").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
  xmlhttp.open("POST","link[1]",true);
  xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
  xmlhttp.send();
}
```

The link[1] outputs the following:

```
<select name="sets">
<option value="1">One</option>
<option value="2">Two</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Form elements need to be added to the DOM. Injecting them via innerHTML isn't the same.

Comment: FYI, you misspelled "Title" on the second line in your first block of code.

Answer (score 0):

I see more `</div>`s than `<div>`s in your HTML. I suspect that the HTML that you're generating is invalid, and the `<form>` element is being implicitly closed sooner than you want it to be -- thus, the element you're injecting isn't in the form.

Viewing the resulting DOM tree in something like Chrome's "Inspect Element" may be instructive.

Comment: The missing <div> are there in the original code, so that shouldn't be  the problem.

Comment: Either way, give the DOM tree a look!